# Why does gprof occasionally not print number of calls for particular functions?

Tags: c, debugging, profiling, gprof

The application is compiled with -O0 -g -pg and gprof is run with its default settings.

Comment: Some people will say" tell your version and program", but it's all BS.  I think that this is a very good question in its current form.  +1

Comment: An only question: does "occasionally" mean that if you run it on the same program to profile, it sometimes prints the number, and sometimes it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(self-answer) I believe it was static declarations.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how did you overcome these static declarations? I didn't get what do you mean by static declarations.

Comment: GPROF does not report the number of calls, self and total call cycles for statically declared functions. See the following post on this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617454/view-static-calls-in-gprof-output

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that all of your modules have the -pg flag.  If any one is missing it, you could have these results.

Comment: I checked for -pg flag, which is enabled for all the modules, but still it does not print number of calls.